# SVD of concatenate matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

Let $X \in \mathbf{R}^{n\times m}$ be split into two sub matrices, $X = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    X_0 \\
    X_1
  \end{bmatrix}
$, if $X_0 = U_0 \Sigma_0 V_0^T$ and $X_1 = U_1 \Sigma_1 V_1^T$ can we say anything about the SVD of $X$, or at least have a good starting point for an iterative method?